# Page widget or plugin that does the 'Recent Activity' effect on foursquare.com?

Tags: css, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I like the 'Recent Activity' effect on http://foursquare.com/. The top activity pushing all beneath. Is there a JQuery plugin or widget I can readily use which does the same?

(I am a lazy developer so please no 'you can develop this yourself' responses)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Spy](http://leftlogic.com/lounge/articles/jquery_spy2/) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That can be achieved using the default jQuery slide() function, what happens  is that the new item on the list comes with a slide (show) and the last one with a slide (hide) in it.

Info on the function: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide